# Path helper for a wildcard route in Phoenix (Elixir)

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'd like to use a path helper for a wildcard route, defined like this:

```
get("/thing/*sub_path", ThingController, :index)
```

There is indeed a path helper, but it does is of course not what I need :

```
iex(3)> MyAppWeb.Router.Helpers.thing_path(MyAppWeb.Endpoint, :index, sub_path: "test/thing")
"/thing?sub_path=test%2Fthing"
```

What I need would be, instead:

```
"/thing/test/thing"
```

Any clue on how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
get("/thing/*sub_path", ThingController, :index)
```

and this:

```
MyAppWeb.Router.Helpers.thing_path(MyAppWeb.Endpoint, :index, ["test", "thing"])
```

Example: https://gist.github.com/tapajos/b48e0d1b8ef6654ad70a220c8dc1a97c